# PyVISA: cannot connect via VICP to LeCroy scope

Tags: python, visa

I'm trying to connect to a LeCroy Wavesurfer 400 series via their VICP VISA passport (TCP/IP) with PyVISA 1.7 under Windows7/32bit and NI-VISA 5.4.1:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
scope = rm.open_resource("VICP::169.254.201.2::INSTR")
print(scope.query("*IDN?"))
```

I get the following error:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 1378
>       alias_if_exists)
>
> VisaIOWarning: VI_WARN_EXT_FUNC_NIMPL (1073676457): The operation succeeded, but a lower level driver did not implement the extended functionality.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\path\scopeTest.py", 
>   line 4, in  scope = rm.open_resource("VICP::169.254.201.2::INSTR")
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", 
>   line 1614, in >open_resource
>      info = self.resource_info(resource_name)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", 
>   line 1584, in >resource_info
>
> raise ValueError('Could not parse resource: %s (error code %s)' % >(resource_name, ret))
>
> **ValueError: Could not parse resource**: VICP::169.254.201.2::INSTR (error code None)

Under LabVIEW connection to and communication with the device under this VICP address works. Also, when using `TCPIP::` instead of `VICP::` in `open_resource()` connection is established without warnings and errors and `print(scope.ask("*IDN?"))` works, but other device commands as `scope.write("C1:VDIV .02")` do not work

```
print(scope.query("C1:VDIV .02"))
WARNING : CURRENT REMOTE CONTROL INTERFACE IS TCPI
```

concluding that for correct device control the VICP passport has to be used.
When using PyVISA 1.5 but otherwise same configuration and trying to connect via:

```
scope = visa.instrument("VICP::169.254.201.2::INSTR")
```

gives:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 1208
>       alias_if_exists)
>
> VisaIOWarning: VI_WARN_EXT_FUNC_NIMPL (1073676457): The operation succeeded, but a lower level driver did not implement the extended functionality.
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 315
>      return Instrument(resource_name, resource_manager=self, **kwargs)
>
> UserWarning: given resource was not an INSTR but Unknown

For earlier versions of PyVISA this was discussed for an empty string return of the instrument:

http://osdir.com/ml/python.pyvisa.devel/2007-07/msg00003.html
and
http://sourceforge.net/p/pyvisa/bugs/5/

I suspect the problem to be the **InterfaceType** in *C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\constants.py* not to exist for the VICP connection protocol in PyVISA. When `resource_info()`, the line that throws the error, in *C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py* is called

> ```
> def resource_info(self, resource_name):  
>        """Get the extended information of a particular resource
>
>       :param resource_name: Unique symbolic name of a resource.
>
>       :rtype: :class:`pyvisa.highlevel.ResourceInfo`
>       """
>       ret, err = self.visalib.parse_resource_extended(self.session, resource_name)
>       if err == constants.StatusCode.success:
>           return ret
>       raise ValueError('Could not parse resource: %s (error code %s)' %(resource_name, ret))
> ```

seems to result in a mismatch with the *interface_type*, or might it be a problem with the *resource_class* and a return issue as with the older versions of PyVISA?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the OP did eventually get this resolved, as per  https://github.com/hgrecco/pyvisa/issues/168. In this thread, **hgrecco** (Hernan Grecco) says "I have implemented a way to force the resource python class to use."

The solution given there seems to work for me:

```
import visa
from pyvisa.resources import MessageBasedResource
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
scope = rm.open_resource('VICP::192.168.1.109::INSTR', resource_pyclass=MessageBasedResource)
```